# Packet vs Circuit switching

Tags: switch, ethernet, ip, switching

I have a 1Mb/s link each user uses 100Kb/s when active.

With 10 user active 10% of the time, I can have 10 users in a circuit switched environment. Packet switching with 35 users, probability > 10 active at the same time is less than .0004.

How did the author come to this conclusion.

Reference: Network Top Down Approach 7th

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Circuit switched: each user needs 1/10 of link, so can reserve only 10 channels on the link, whether they are using it 10% or 100%.

Packet switched: Each user is using the channel 10% of the time, so probability of a given user being active is *p* = 0.1, and inactive *q* = 0.9.  It's a binomial distribution *X ~ B(35, 0.1)*, so probability *Pr(X=k) = C(35, k) p<sup>k</sup> q<sup>(35-k)</sup>*.  You need *Pr(X>10)* which is *1 - Pr(X<=10)* which is *1-(Pr(X=0) + Pr(X=1) + ... Pr(X=10))*.

I actually get 0.000424, not "less than 0.0004".

Description https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function
Calculate it here: https://stattrek.com/online-calculator/binomial.aspx

[EDIT to add] It needs to be said both of those include a great deal of assumption and modelling simplifications. In the case of circuit switching, you can do overbooking (in the [way of airlines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overselling#Transportation)), especially if you know that the channels are only used a certain percentage and you have enough of them to average well.  In the case of packet switching, the model assumes they are independent and evenly distributed; again these are reasonable if the number of hosts is large.